# Django : Syncdb incorrectly warns that many-to-many field is stale

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a django application where one application has many-to-many relationship with a UserProfile. But whenever I do a syncdb, it warns me that app_users is stale field

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:
     Apps | app_users

#settings.py
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'kprofile.UserProfile'

#Apps/models.py
class app(models.Model):
    ....
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)
```

Now I don't use UserProfile inside view except for some authentication purposes inside rules. And a UserProfile can be attached to an App only from admin interface. How can I stop django syncdb from giving me this false/incorrect warning?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pay attention to the message. It's not claiming that your field is stale - it's talking about an entry in the [Content Types](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) model.

In the shell, do this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='Apps', model='app_users')
ct.delete()
```

Comment: Followed your commands and printed ct. ct => <ContentType: app-userprofile relationship>. I would think that is a valid relationship.

Comment: Nothing to do with whether it's valid. That CT no longer points to the correct place. Delete it and run syncdb, which will recreate it properly.

Comment: I took a deep breath(i'm working directly on production server) and typed "yes" at the prompt. Apparently everything is still working correctly. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If you need a silent statement that doesn't throw exceptions: `ContentType.objects.filter(app_label='Apps', model='app_users').delete()`