# stale content types while syncdb in Django

Tags: python, django, syncdb, contenttypes

While I'm trying to `syncdb` for my django project, I'm seeing following complains:

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

myapp | 

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
```

While I've also read the similar problem [django-syncdb-many-to-many-stale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510843/django-syncdb-incorrectly-warns-that-many-to-many-field-is-stale), but I cannot risk myself typing `yes` since I'm on prod instance.

Would `yes` **safely** delete those stale entries in contenttype?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally you can delete them safely, as these are content types where no model exists anymore.
The only thing you should be aware of is, that if you had other models pointing to the `ContentType` model via a `ForeignKey` these objects will be deleted as well. If you didn't set any foreign keys to `ContentType` at all nothing bad can happen, if you did evaluate if you would still need the objects that have a foreign key to the content type you are about to delete (if there are any).

Comment: thanks. `ForeignKey` matters indeed. I think I'll have to **verify** after `syncdb` to ensure the security.

Comment: I have a problem: each time I run "migrate", it asks for it, even if I dont touch anything.